# get line from matrix AVX

Tags: c++, matrix, avx, avx512

Good morning,

As I'm working with avx a lot lately, I have been facing a problem. I cannot fully understand how this works.

So I have a matrix of 8x8. And I want to have in the variable called "line" the 1st line of this matrix. In my code when I try to print the line[0] to line[3] (more than 3 gives core dumped even tho I want the whole line of 8 values) I get two lines sometimes all the lines but not the fully one and first line.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 4) {

      //take 1st line of matrix A
      __m256 line = _mm256_load_ps(&A[i * N + j]);
      

    }
  }
```

Comment: `j += 4` increments by 4 floats, half of a `__m256`.  But you're using aligned loads (`load` not `loadu`) of 8 floats, so either the first or 2nd won't be aligned.  (The 2nd, if the whole matrix is aligned by 32).  If you want whole rows of an 8x8 matrix, you don't need an inner loop if you're using `__m256` AVX vectors that hold 8 floats, 32 bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't need an inner loop ? so I just perform `for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i += 1) { __m256 line = _mm256_load_ps(&A[i]);}` in order to get each line of the matrix A?

Comment: No, you still have to do the 2D indexing, like `&A[i*N + 0]` which with `_mm256_load_ps` loads the 8 floats from `A[i*N + 0..7]`.  `_mm256_load_ps` needs the address of the first of the 8 floats you want it to load.  I assume you understand how the 2D indexing into a 64-element array works...

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay so using `_mm256_load_ps` on `&A[i*N + 0]` we will load `A[i*N + 0] to A[i*N + 7]`. Got it! I will try to understand also why you mentionned `loadsu` and thank you for you answer and time.